# Offline googlespeech recognition API

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I have developed a speech recognition app using google's speech recognition API using JavaScript, it all works fine. But according to my user's requirements i need to make it offline. I don't want to use Microsoft's SAPI because it's less efficient and a little bit  complicated. Therefore i am asking if there is a way through which i can make this google's API work offline on a windows PC and not android or even any other API that can work wih either C++, Java, or python. What matters is an efficient one because the text output is the most important in my system.

Comment: No, there is no way

Comment: As a speech recognition expert what do you recommend  Nikolay?

Comment: Use open source library or SAPI, that would not be so easy though.

Comment: I find SAPI to be inefficient.